# Is there a reason why wavelet in continuous wavelet transform are symmetric?

Tags: signal-detection, pywavelets, fast-wavelet-transform

I have looked at several packages to do continuous wavelet transform (cwt), and the usable wavelet families that are available are always symmetric. Is there a reason for that? The kind of signals I am studying can be highly asymmetric sometimes, so I would like to do cwt with asymmetric wavelets.

Answer (score 1):

Continuous wavelets do not need to be symmetric. Due to their high redundancy, mathematical conditions for a function to be an admissible wavelet are quite mild. In a nutshell, integrability, zero-mean and fast decay in the frequency domain are "enough".

Issues arise when one wants non-redundant critically discretized wavelets. For two-band discrete wavelets, finite support, orthogonality, real-values and symmetry properties cannot be meet together, except for Haar wavelets. Hence, most standard orthogonal discrete wavelets are not symmetric.

Let  remember that in standard signal/image processing, symmetry is common in windows, filters, transforms. Therefore, in continuous wavelets as well, symmetry is commonly used. Symmetry limits dependence on the arrow of time (mirror invariance), and ease interpretation of wavelet coefficients.

Therefore, you can choose non-symmetric continuous  wavelets to study non-symmetric signals. However, the combination of asymmetries is no guarantee of better results.

Comment: Alright.. but if there is no inherent mathematical reason as to why I cannot do it, why can't I find any package to do that? Do you know something like that? It does not need to be in python

Comment: At first glance, I'd say that the degrees of freedom are so huge that people prefer design wavelets on positive properties (are orthogonal, are narrow, are tight, are symmetric) which can be implemented, instead of "non properties" (not narrow, not tight...) Packages need discretization, and as long you want an inverse, one needs some guarantees

Comment: I have been working in seismic processing for a while. There, "physical wavelets" are mostly asymmetric. Yet, I have little evidence that asymmetric wavelet programs perform much better symmetric ones. More the converse, so far.